# Why does my Eclipse Indigo crash on Ubuntu 13.04 with Oracle JDK 64bit?

Tags: eclipse, crash, java

I installed jdk and eclipse on to Ubuntu 13.04. It stays open till I create a project and type some basic but then suddenly within a minute when I click somewhere like javadoc or Ctrl+Space, it immediately crashes with the following message. I had this problem with Juno and Ubuntu 12.04, but when I upgraded from Juno to Indigo, it was fine. But now after using Indigo and Ubuntu 13.04 it's all messed up. Even Juno won't work with Ubuntu 13.04, I need help. I need to get eclipse working. I just am ready to install/remove anything to get Eclipse working again.

```
[psycho:~] $ /opt/eclipse/eclipse 

(Eclipse:19297): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "mist",

(Eclipse:19297): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "mist",
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb29dce2009, pid=19297, tid=140405947455232
#
# JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6e009]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x19
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try        "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/psycho/hs_err_pid19297.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

My Logs: [Logs generated by eclipse](http://pastebin.com/t22x4GGR)

Comment: .....An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/psycho/hs_err_pid19297.log .... did u read it already? :)

Comment: An incompatible native library. Will openjdk do?

Comment: I read but could not figure out any reasons on why it was crashing. the hs_err_pid19297.log is at http://pastebin.com/t22x4GGR . Help me if you can sort it.

Comment: I tried openjdk and oracle jdk ... None of them work

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I had the same error running ADT on Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome Shell 3.8.
I found this relevant bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776
And a workaround as posted in the bug report:
Add

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to your `eclipse.ini`
It worked for me, I hope it solves the problem for you as well.

Comment: Add to the End of `eclipse.ini`.  By reading that link, looks success is dependent on the Firefox version (the xulrunner version).

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04, and this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. tried the workaround they have mentioned and it's of no use.

Comment: I added in eclipse.ini but still eclipse is crash.

Comment: Fixed same problem with ZendStudio 9.0 after 13.10 -> 14.04 migration

Comment: @RudraMurthy, make sure that you add the parameter after the `-vmargs` line in `eclipse.ini`

Comment: Worked for me after facing this problem when updated from 13.10 to 14.04

Comment: Eclipse still closing automatic...any other solution !

Answer (score 6):

I am running eclipse luna on Ubuntu 12.04 and facing the same problem. I resolved it by adding the following line in eclipse.ini file as other options didn't work for me.

```
-Dorg.jboss.tools.vpe.loadxulrunner=false
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be an Ubuntu / GTK themes problem.  According to [this page](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/gtk-warning-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module_path-pixmap/) on "Ubuntu Technical", it is caused by a missing GTK "theme engine" package.  The fix is to identify the specific GTK theme engine package for the "mist" theme ... or just install theme engines by installing the package "gtk-engines" ([source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=367889#p367889)).

Answer (score 2):

Note that https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776 has been fixed, so the best way of avoiding this crash is to use Eclipse 4.3.2 or newer if you can.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the problem with [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339174) and the workaround was to change the GTK theme (System Settings > Application appearence > GTK).

Answer (score 0):

In my case , the problem was solved by adding the following to the end of eclipse.ini

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```