# Eclipse Kepler crashes regularly on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, ubuntu, subclipse

It often happens when i synchronize my workbench.
I use subclipse with svn version 1.7.9.

already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384754/835703 but it didn't help.

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/home/user/opt/jdk1.7/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: In your home folder you need to check the crash report log file. There may be multiple reasons to crash. It may crash on content assist invocation or when we are synchronizing workspace with source repo. When I re-start the eclipse it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java VM is not working properly. Please check that it is installed as "usr/local/java" and not in any particular user profile.

Comment: Why is that a problem to put it into a user profile?