# Eclipse e4 Kepler SR2 crashes on Kubuntu 14.04 when hovering over a Java element

Tags: eclipse, webkit, jvm-crash

The Java runtime reports:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe7241924cf, pid=9456, tid=140630721804032
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xc4cf]  _dl_rtld_di_serinfo+0x2dbf
```

The Java stack in the `hs_err_pid*.log` looks like this:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK._webkit_web_view_new()J+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK.webkit_web_view_new()J+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebKit.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+212
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+81
j  org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.isAvailable(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+12
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer from [Why does my Eclipse Indigo crash on Ubuntu 13.04 with Oracle JDK 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383992/why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit) worked for me:

Append

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to the end of your `eclipse.ini` (specifically after the `-vmargs` option).

If you now get crashes in XULRunner, disable that as well:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/dev/null
```