# Eclipse crashes when it tries to auto-fill option for populating the methods

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash

I am using Eclipse, Juno version. It loads well. But when it tries to use the autofill features for methods pop-down, it crashes. With the following log:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f66acbd82a1, pid=6895, tid=140080532424448
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b14) (build 1.7.0_55-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/nithin/hs_err_pid6895.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Tried the answer by the [BugZilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776#c6) as the log inicated. But still it's the same. Any ideas to resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also had this problem.  However, thanks to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383992/why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit) thread, I fixed it by adding `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` to my eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I Updated the sdk, updated the eclipse and added that -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla to the end of the eclipse.ini file. Now it seems to work fine. Hopefully.