# eclipse juno (new version of ADT) always crashes in ubuntu 14.04 and create an error log file

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-juno, ubuntu-14.04, error-log

I started android development and I downloaded the latest version of adt available on developer.android.com for linux OS. Now my eclipse crashes automatically without any prior error or notice and it creates an err log file in the same directory, also my virtual device(emulator) is not working in this.
[image]

now what can I do. I tried to re install this but same problem occurs and also it works fine if I use previous version of ADT.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem for couple of weeks now. Adding the following line to the `eclipse.ini` file has solved my problem. Give it a try and hope it helps.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening when i add this to ini file. This seems to do the job

Comment: yes it solved the problem initially but still we have some frequent hangs

Answer (score 2):

tweak the following params in your eclipse.ini and then start eclipse:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

These should help you in running eclipse smoothly.

Thanks

Comment: Are these parameters dependent on the size of installed RAM?

Comment: I have the same params and still i face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. For me this -D tricks did not work (Using juno included in adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702 on ubuntu 14.04).

But [somewhere here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501) I found the suggestion to do a

`sudo apt-get purge libwebkitgtk-1.0-common`

which made it work for me, but then without any html-rendering (brutal, because this deinstalls different things which depend on that, like gimp)

This seems to be related to [why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383992/why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit)