# My Eclipse is automatically closing when ever i start

Tags: eclipse

When ever i trying to open eclipse (Juno) it automatically closing after closing eclipse it generating following log message. After eclipse installing i installed latest version of Android plugins.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fab9c2852a1, pid=18856, tid=140378684942080
#
# JRE version: 6.0_31-b31
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fac6c009800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=18857, stack(0x00007fac75966000,0x00007fac75a67000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000



Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK._soup_session_feature_detach(JJ)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK.soup_session_feature_detach(JJ)V+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebKit.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+920
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+81
j  org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.isAvailable(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover$HoverControlCreator.doCreateInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator.createInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.getInformationControl()Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+176
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.internalShowInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/Rectangle;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.presentInformation()V+70
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.presentInformation()V+64
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager.doPresentInformation()V+1
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$5.run()V+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+61
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+578
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fac6ddc5800 JavaThread "LogCat output receiver for BX903A609J" [_thread_blocked, id=19014, stack(0x00007fabe126a000,0x00007fabe136b000)]
  0x00007fabf034f800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=19010, stack(0x00007fabe315c000,0x00007fabe325d000)]
  0x00007faba8002000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=18988, stack(0x00007fabe3560000,0x00007fabe3661000)]
  0x00007fabb8001000 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=18987, stack(0x00007fabe325d000,0x00007fabe335e000)]
  0x00007fabd80b1000 JavaThread "Device Client Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=18972, stack(0x00007fac14165000,0x00007fac14266000)]
  0x00007fabdc036800 JavaThread "Device List Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=18971, stack(0x00007fac14266000,0x00007fac14367000)]
  0x00007fabdc005800 JavaThread "Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=18962, stack(0x00007fabe335e000,0x00007fabe345f000)]
  0x00007fac6cee5800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18941, stack(0x00007fabe345f000,0x00007fabe3560000)]
  0x00007fabdc001000 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=18925, stack(0x00007fabe3661000,0x00007fabe3762000)]
  0x00007fac6cb2f800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18900, stack(0x00007fabe3eff000,0x00007fabe4000000)]
  0x00007fabf0004000 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=18898, stack(0x00007fac14428000,0x00007fac14529000)]
  0x00007fac001c3000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18897, stack(0x00007fac14529000,0x00007fac1462a000)]
  0x00007fac00049800 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=18896, stack(0x00007fac146b1000,0x00007fac147b2000)]
  0x00007fac6c769000 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=18895, stack(0x00007fac174da000,0x00007fac175db000)]
  0x00007fabf4009000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18891, stack(0x00007fac177dd000,0x00007fac178de000)]
  0x00007fac081d4800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=18882, stack(0x00007fac175db000,0x00007fac176dc000)]
  0x00007fac0808e000 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18881, stack(0x00007fac176dc000,0x00007fac177dd000)]
  0x00007fac08021000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18879, stack(0x00007fac178de000,0x00007fac179df000)]
  0x00007fac6c453000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18878, stack(0x00007fac179df000,0x00007fac17ae0000)]
  0x00007fac6c473000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18877, stack(0x00007fac17ae0000,0x00007fac17be1000)]
  0x00007fac6c439000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=18876, stack(0x00007fac20100000,0x00007fac20201000)]
  0x00007fac6c103000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18872, stack(0x00007fac521e6000,0x00007fac522e7000)]
  0x00007fac6c100800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18871, stack(0x00007fac522e7000,0x00007fac523e8000)]
  0x00007fac6c0fe000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18870, stack(0x00007fac523e8000,0x00007fac524e9000)]
  0x00007fac6c0fb800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18869, stack(0x00007fac524e9000,0x00007fac525ea000)]
  0x00007fac6c0ad000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18868, stack(0x00007fac52ccc000,0x00007fac52dcd000)]
  0x00007fac6c0ab000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18867, stack(0x00007fac52dcd000,0x00007fac52ece000)]
=>0x00007fac6c009800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=18857, stack(0x00007fac75966000,0x00007fac75a67000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007fac6c09c000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007fac52ece000,0x00007fac52fcf000] [id=18866]
  0x00007fac6c10e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007fac520e5000,0x00007fac521e6000] [id=18873]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 135872K, used 19434K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 99072K, 19% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f685aa58,0x00000000fb620000)
  from space 36800K, 0% used [0x00000000fdc10000,0x00000000fdc10000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 37824K, 0% used [0x00000000fb620000,0x00000000fb620000,0x00000000fdb10000)
 ParOldGen       total 156032K, used 131851K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e9860000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 156032K, 84% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e80c2f30,0x00000000e9860000)
 PSPermGen       total 129280K, used 86091K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d7e40000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 129280K, 66% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d5412dc8,0x00000000d7e40000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00007fac7255c000,0x00007fac726dd000] byte_map_base: 0x00007fac71edc000

Polling page: 0x00007fac75a88000

Code Cache  [0x00007fac69000000, 0x00007fac69aa0000, 0x00007fac6c000000)
 total_blobs=3421 nmethods=2713 adapters=658 free_code_cache=38463Kb largest_free_block=39209280

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 188.009 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 2953             org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText::getLineHeight (118 bytes)
Event: 188.016 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 nmethod 2953 0x00007fac69a6fb90 code [0x00007fac69a6fde0, 0x00007fac69a70590]
Event: 188.730 Thread 0x00007fac6c0fe000 2954   !         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner::getNextToken (3636 bytes)
Event: 188.731 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800   74 % !         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser::parse @ 37 (761 bytes)
Event: 188.761 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 nmethod 74% 0x00007fac69a78b50 code [0x00007fac69a78fe0, 0x00007fac69a7aea0]
Event: 188.761 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 2955   !         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner::jumpOverMethodBody (1839 bytes)
Event: 188.793 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 nmethod 2955 0x00007fac69a81250 code [0x00007fac69a81820, 0x00007fac69a840e8]
Event: 188.810 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 2956   !         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser::parse (761 bytes)
Event: 188.837 Thread 0x00007fac6c100800 nmethod 2956 0x00007fac69a8c890 code [0x00007fac69a8cd00, 0x00007fac69a8ed50]
Event: 188.838 Thread 0x00007fac6c0fe000 nmethod 2954 0x00007fac69a91010 code [0x00007fac69a91d80, 0x00007fac69a97730]
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Can you please help above issue

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383992/why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit). _Its for Ubuntu 13.04 with 64 bit Java_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776#c6

There is a workaround to add following in eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case removing libwebkitgtk-1.0-common solved the problem. This solution was mentioned here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501